# I am incrementing the value and update it to the table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace trigger trans_s_t5
after insert
on trans_s
for each row
begin
update :old.no_of_books
set book_no=:old.no_of_books+1
where book_no=:trans_s.book_no;
end;
```

Getting error as:

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.NO_OF_BOOKS' Compilation failed, line 3
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.NO_OF_BOOKS' Compilation failed, line 4
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'TRANS_S.BOOK_NO' Compilation failed, line 2 
PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name Compilation failed, line 2 (10:11:17)
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: what do you want to update? A table? You can't use :old and :new with tables. Only with specific column

Comment: and what is :trans_s?

Comment: post your table structure

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to change the value of a field in the TRANS_S table in this trigger, which is defined on the TRANS_S table. If so, you can do this by changing your trigger to a BEFORE trigger and updating the field directly, as in:

```
create or replace trigger trans_s_t5
  BEFORE insert on trans_s
  for each row
begin
  :NEW.NO_OF_BOOKS := :NEW.NO_OF_BOOKS + 1;
end;
```

Best of luck.